# Normally Closed, 24V DC, 1/4 NPT Female, 1.4 Cv solenoid valve power supply

Tags: power-supply, electrical, solenoid-valve, 24v

I have a solenoid valve of Normally Closed, 24V DC, 1/4 NPT Female, 1.4 Cv, 500mA max current drawn.

Can somebody verify the power supply requirement.
would this be an ideal power supply unit for the above mentioned solenoid valve?

- [POWER SUPPLY](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/MEAN-WELL/MPM-45-24?qs=GBLSl2Akirv1e7cTcBfw5Q%3D%3D).
- [SOLENOID VALVE](https://www.mcmaster.com/4711K512/)

Comment: Note that the pipe thread, gender and Cv are irrelevant to the question of solenoid power consumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 45W supply might need a reverse 1N400x diode across the coil pair at the source on the open flyback effect. The 12W coil is adequately driven.
Use twist pair or better shielded twisted pair (STP) with shield earth coupled to reduce flyback EMI.

Comment: would there be a power supply module that comes ready made, that i can buy off the shelf,that you could recommend?

Comment: This site forbids that https://www.amazon.com/AVAWO-Switching-Transformer-Regulated-Computer/dp/B0146IAXYO/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=DY09LK6URP5T&dchild=1&keywords=24v+power+supply&qid=1598476899&s=industrial&sprefix=24%2Cindustrial%2C173&sr=1-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyUkdRWDdSWTA1UzlNJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMzg1ODMzMVozNTg0Qko2VTVTQSZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNzg4Mzc4MVFIN0NXRVlEMTI4OCZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=. This is cheaper and has excess power, but if you switch the DC side, you still want to use a cheap 1N400x x=1 to 7 1A diode

Comment: See how in searches for relay diode and you still need a cordset

Answer (score 0):

For actuating a solenoid valve, an unregulated power supply would suffice.

[image]

A freewheeling diode would be required, across the solenoid coil.

[image]